# Using JavaScript filter, How can I write this by dynamically getting the month from the same array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, c3.js

```
        let janFilteredData = YearlyExpense.filter((data) => {
        return data.month === "January"
    })
    let febFilteredData = YearlyExpense.filter((data) => {
        return data.month === "February"
    })
    let marFilteredData = YearlyExpense.filter((data) => {
        return data.month === "March"
    })
    .
    .
    .
    . 
    .

    let decFilteredData = YearlyExpense.filter((data) => {
        return data.month === "December"
    })
```

I need to pass the value to c3 chart as the total number of expenses in every month since I'm showing bar graph for every month present.

The YearlyExpense array is;

```
const MonthlyExpense = [{
UserID: "1",
UserName: "George",
MonthlyExpenseDetails:[
    {
        TotalAmount: "70000",
        TotalNoOfBills: 16,
        ExpenseTypeDetails: [
            {
                BillType: "Taxi",
                NoOfBills: 4,
                Amount: "30000",
                Approved: {
                    TotalAmount: 10000,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 1
                },
                Rejected: {
                    TotalAmount: 10000,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 0
                },
                Pending: {
                    TotalAmount: 10000,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 3
                }
            },
            {
                BillType: "Food",
                NoOfBills: 4,
                Amount: "10000",
                Approved: {
                    TotalAmount: 10000,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 1
                },
                Rejected: {
                    TotalAmount: 0,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 0
                },
                Pending: {
                    TotalAmount: 0,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 3
                }
            },
            {
                BillType: "Fine",
                NoOfBills: 4,
                Amount: "30000",
                Approved: {
                    TotalAmount: 10000,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 1
                },
                Rejected: {
                    TotalAmount: 0,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 0
                },
                Pending: {
                    TotalAmount: 20000,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 3
                }
            }
        ]
    },
]},

{
UserID: "2",
UserName: "Figo",
MonthlyExpenseDetails:[
    {
        TotalAmount: "80000",
        TotalNoOfBills: 16,
        ExpenseTypeDetails: [
            {
                BillType: "Taxi",
                NoOfBills: 4,
                Amount: "30000",
                Approved: {
                    TotalAmount: 10000,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 1
                },
                Rejected: {
                    TotalAmount: 0,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 0
                },
                Pending: {
                    TotalAmount: 20000,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 3
                }
            },
            {
                BillType: "Food",
                NoOfBills: 4,
                Amount: "10000",
                Approved: {
                    TotalAmount: 0,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 1
                },
                Rejected: {
                    TotalAmount: 5000,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 0
                },
                Pending: {
                    TotalAmount: 5000,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 3
                }
            },
            {
                BillType: "Fine",
                NoOfBills: 4,
                Amount: "7100",
                Approved: {
                    TotalAmount: 6000,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 1
                },
                Rejected: {
                    TotalAmount: 100,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 0
                },
                Pending: {
                    TotalAmount: 1000,
                    TotalNoOfBills: 3
                }
            }
        ]
    },
]}]

export const YearlyExpense = [
{ month: "January", expense: MonthlyExpense },
{ month: "February", expense: MonthlyExpense },
{ month: "March", expense: MonthlyExpense },
{ month: "April", expense: MonthlyExpense },
{ month: "May", expense: MonthlyExpense },
{ month: "June", expense: MonthlyExpense },
{ month: "July", expense: MonthlyExpense },
{ month: "August", expense: MonthlyExpense },
{ month: "September", expense: MonthlyExpense },
{ month: "October", expense: MonthlyExpense },
{ month: "November", expense: MonthlyExpense },
{ month: "December", expense: MonthlyExpense }]
```

I am generating this data for react c3js graph. In this case, how can I get the data according to respective month without repeating the code as stated above.

Comment: what is data and what is expected output ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
function monthlyFilteredData(yearlyExpense,month){
  return yearlyExpense.filter(data => data.month === month)
}

let janFilteredData = monthlyFilteredData(yearlyExpense, 'January')
let febFilteredData = monthlyFilteredData(yearlyExpense, 'February')
let marFilteredData = monthlyFilteredData(yearlyExpense, 'March')
```

so on.

Answer (score 0):

Compose an array of month

```
let months= ['January', 'February', 'March', 'May', 'June'] //complete array
```

To dinamically build list of monts from YearlyExpense use the following:

```
let months = YearlyExpense.map((item) => item.month)
```

And then perform map function

```
let result = months.map((item) => ({[item]: YearlyExpense.filter((data) => 
        data.month === item)}))
```

This will get results in the format of array with objects, where key is month name and value is filter results. e.g. `[{"January": <data here>}, {"February": <data here>}]`

If you need only the data, just add the result of filtering, e.g.:

```
let months= ['January', 'February', 'March', 'May', 'June'] //complete array

let result = months.map((item) => YearlyExpense.filter((data) => 
        data.month === item))
```

If you need structure like this `{ month: "January", expense: MonthlyExpense }` then:

```
 let months= ['January', 'February', 'March', 'May', 'June'] //complete array

    let result = months.map((item) => ({month: item, expense: YearlyExpense.filter((data) => 
            data.month === item)}))
```